# Merging multiple columns in single data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a bizarre problem where I've combined together several data frames that have different species abundance data. I used rbind.fill() to collate the data frames, but some of the columns names for like species are spelled slightly differently, hence, for several species I have 2-3 columns.

Does anyone know of a way I can merge the data from these columns together?

Simple example:

```
dat <- matrix(data=c(
    Sp.a=c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
    Sp.b=c(3,4,5,6,7,5,4,6,3,4), 
    Sp.c=c(4,4,4,3,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
    Spp.A=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,3,4,2,3), 
    Spp.C=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,4,2,5,4)
    ), 10,5)

colnames(dat)<- c("Sp.a", "Sp.b", "Sp.c", "Spp.A", "Spp.C")

dat
      sp.a  sp.b sp.c Spp.A Spp.C
 [1,]    1    3    4    NA    NA
 [2,]    2    4    4    NA    NA
 [3,]    3    5    4    NA    NA
 [4,]    4    6    3    NA    NA
 [5,]    5    7    2    NA    NA
 [6,]   NA    5   NA     2     3
 [7,]   NA    4   NA     3     4
 [8,]   NA    6   NA     4     2
 [9,]   NA    3   NA     2     5
 [10,]  NA    4   NA     3     4
```

How can I get sp.a and Spp.A into a single column? (same for sp.c and Spp.C).

Thanks for any help,
Paul

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest just to rename the columns in the original frames so that the names match?

Comment: Probably, but I hate manipulating raw data in the original files. That is typically my last resort; right after posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: well, not editing in rawdata, just using `sub("Spp","Sp", vectorofNames)` , wouldn't that be easier

Answer (score 1):

```
ColsToMerge <- c("sp.a", "Spp.A")
dat[["A.merged"]] <- 
     apply(dat[, ColsToMerge], 1, function(rr) ifelse(is.na(rr[[1]]), rr[[2]], rr[[1]]))
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. This didn't seem to work. I get a match.fun(FUN) error. argument FUN is missing.

Comment: @Paul, that was a typo on my part, leaving out the `1`.  Please try again

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. This is pretty general, and would even work if you had one series divided over three or more columns.

```
dat <- data.frame(dat)
# get the last letter of each column and make it lowercase, 
# we'll be grouping the columns by this
ns <- tolower(gsub('^.+\\.', '', names(dat)))
# group the columns by their last letter, and run each group through pmax
result <- lapply(split.default(dat, ns), function(x) do.call(function(...) pmax(..., na.rm=TRUE), x))
do.call(cbind, result)
#       a b c
#  [1,] 1 3 4
#  [2,] 2 4 4
#  [3,] 3 5 4
#  [4,] 4 6 3
#  [5,] 5 7 2
#  [6,] 2 5 3
#  [7,] 3 4 4
#  [8,] 4 6 2
#  [9,] 2 3 5
# [10,] 3 4 4
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks, this worked great...with one slight issue. In my actual data set I have species abundance data as well as biomass data. So, for each species I have a "pct.spp" column as well as a "spp.wt", column. These all got merged with your code. Any thoughts?

Comment: consider selecting those columns out, so just the columns of the type you include in your posting are left. Then run this, and `cbind` the result to the other columns you selected out.

Comment: duh...why didn't I think of that. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: sure, don't forget to accept once you're satisfied with in an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2` and going from long --> wide --> long(again) format:

```
library(reshape2)
## long format
dat.m <- melt(dat)
## remove missing values
dat.m <- dat.m[!is.na(dat.m$value),]
## rename names 
dat.m$Var2 <- tolower(sub("Spp","Sp", dat.m$Var2) )
## wide format
dcast(Var1~Var2,data=dat.m)

   Var1 sp.a sp.b sp.c
1     1    1    3    4
2     2    2    4    4
3     3    3    5    4
4     4    4    6    3
5     5    5    7    2
6     6    2    5    3
7     7    3    4    4
8     8    4    6    2
9     9    2    3    5
10   10    3    4    4
```